# Migration to AndroidX causes hundreds of Jetifier failures

Tags: android, androidx

I used the Migrate to AndroidX refactor, now when I try to build or sync gradle I get hundreds of errors like this:

```
Failed to transform artifact 'materialdrawer-kt.aar (co.zsmb:materialdrawer-kt:1.3.6)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}
```

I've seen references elsewhere to using a Jetify blacklist, but that doesn't seem like a viable solution given the number of packages throwing errors.

Is there some other solution?

Comment: How did you migrated? Manually or let Android Studio do the heavy work?

Comment: to me it happened when using the studio's Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.